# Does object traversing in linear motion have a constant bearing rate?

Tags: kinematics, linear-systems

If an observer is moving at a constant rate and constant direction and another object traverses in front of the observer and is also moving in a fixed direction at a constant rate, will the bearing rate (the change in bearing relative to the observer over time) always be constant?

What would be the way to analyze/prove this using vector notation?

Comment: Consider the case where the two bodies intersect: the change of bearing is then either zero or (at the moment of intersection) infinite.

Answer (score 1):

No. When the other object is far away from the observer the bearing will change very little; when the object is closest to the observer the bearing will change the most.  The 'bearing rate' will only be constant (and equal to zero) when the object and observer are on a parallel course moving in the same direction or when they are moving on the same course (either in the same or the opposite direction).

Analyze using vector subtraction : if the observer has velocity $\vec U$ and the object has velocity $\vec V$ then the relative velocity of the object is $\vec V-\vec U$.

For example, if $\vec U = t\vec i+2t\vec j$ and $\vec V = (3-5t)\vec i+(4-3t)\vec j$ then the relative velocity is
$\vec V-\vec U = (3-6t)\vec i+(4-5t)\vec j$
and the bearing wrt the $+x$ direction is $\theta$ where
$\tan\theta = \frac{4-5t}{3-6t} = \frac{\frac{5}{2}(1-2t) + \frac{3}{2}}{3(1-2t)} = \frac{5}{6} + \frac{1}{2(1-2t)} $.
From this you can find the rate of change of bearing $\frac{d\theta}{dt}$ by differentiating :
$ (1+\tan^2\theta)\frac{d\theta}{dt} = \frac{1}{(1-2t)^2}$
$ (\frac{9(1-2t)^2}{9(1-2t)^2}+\frac{(3-5t)^2}{9(1-2t)^2} )\frac{d\theta}{dt} = \frac{1}{(1-2t)^2}$
$ (9(1-4t+4t^2) + (9-30t+25t^2) )\frac{d\theta}{dt} = 9 $
$ \frac{d\theta}{dt} = \frac{9}{(18-66t+61t^2)} = \frac{9}{61(t-\frac{33}{61})^2 + \frac{18}{61}}$.
The maximum value of $\frac{d\theta}{dt}$ occurs when $ t=\frac{33}{61}$ and is $\frac{61}{2}$.